# Debugging ELPA and Emacs connection issues behind a corporate proxy

Tags: package-repositories, proxy

I'm having trouble getting to ELPA behind our corporate proxy. I see proxy traffic attempting to `CONNECT` to the ELPA domain which then fails. How can I turn on debugging to see the exact URL that Emacs is trying to access? `-debug-init` didn't work for me with Emacs 27.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a variable for debugging URL calls, `url-debug`, set it to true:

```
(setq url-debug t)
```

Use the function `url-retrieve-synchronously`, this will create a debug buffer called ***URL-DEBUG*** and there you can see all the debug output from the call:

```
(url-retrieve-synchronously (url-generic-parse-url "https://elpa.gnu.org/"))
```

Comment: thanks for your help. It wasn't as useful as I've hoped. I posted a follow up question, which I was hoping you might take a look at: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/60228/cannot-access-elpa-from-emacs-behind-a-corporate-proxy-mac