# Cannot access ELPA from Emacs behind a corporate proxy (Mac)

Tags: package-repositories, gnutls, proxy

I'm having trouble accessing ELPA on my Mac from behind a corporate proxy. Emacs 27.1.

I have `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` configured appropriately (I've also tried setting `url-proxy-services`).

**From Emacs** (`M-x package-refresh-contents`):

```
Using a proxy for https...
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:443
elpa.gnu.org/0 nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Package refresh done
Failed to download ‘gnu’ archive.
```

**From Terminal**:

```
hostname:~ 000$ gnutls-cli -V --ca-verification --x509cafile=/tmp/master.pem elpa.gnu.org
Processed 205 CA certificate(s).
Resolving 'elpa.gnu.org:443'...
Cannot resolve elpa.gnu.org:443: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

hostname:~ 000$ nslookup elpa.gnu.org
Server:     XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Address:    XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX#53

** server can't find elpa.gnu.org: NXDOMAIN
```

It looks like `gnutls` and `nslookup` are having trouble resolving the domain (`nodename nor servname provided, or not known` is the same error that Emacs is throwing).

However `curl` has no issues:

```
hostname:~ 000$ curl elpa.gnu.org|head
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>GNU Emacs Lisp Package Archive</title>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Accroding to your last curl command, plain HTTP works, so you can 1) try curl https://elpa.gnu.org to see if it works too, according to my knowledge, with HTTP proxy, the local client doesn't need to resolve the domain, it sends `GET http://elpa.gnu.org/ HTTP/1.1` to the proxy server 2) ask package.el to use HTTP, instead of HTTPS, GNU Elpa supports both.

Comment: Using http makes no difference.

Comment: 1) use http instead of https for ease of debug 2) your network can't access elpa.gnu.org, and your above curl is indeed using your proxy, and your proxy does work, right? 3) "elpa.gnu.org/0 ... or not known" suggests something is wrong with your proxy setting, since you're using proxy, Emacs won't connect to elpa.gnu.org, it should ask your proxy to do. and where does the port number 0 come from? 4) here is an example setting, `(setq url-proxy-services '(("http" . "localhost:1234") ...))`  5) you can test your proxy via `curl -v -x http://localhost:1234 example.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around this issue by using Squid as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11028225/38753). Note that I still see the `elpa.gnu.org/0 nodename nor servname provided, or not known`  error.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs `package.el` supports local package repo.

So here is the solution,

- Create a local repo from your installed packages using https://github.com/redguardtoo/elpa-mirror
- Add local repo path to `package-archives`, then start up Emacs as usual.

```lisp
(setq package-archives '(("myelpa" . "~/myelpa/")))
```

Comment: Unfortunately when you run the alpa-mirror package (following the instructions) in a proxy environment it doesn't work.